# Retrieving nodes from xml document based on date

Tags: c#, datetime, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Basically I have an xml document and i want to retrieve some data based on the release date.

For example, lets assume i have the following xml

```
<books>
    <book>
        <name>Book 1<name>
        <release_date>2011-11-10</release_date>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>Book 2<name>
        <release_date>2012-03-16</release_date>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>Book 3<name>
        <release_date>2010-01-22</release_date>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>Book 4<name>
        <release_date>2011-12-22</release_date>
    </book>
</books>
```

So what i want to have is following for example i pass a date 11/15/2011, and only all documents which were released later should be returned? Any idea how to achieve that?

Is it something like that?:

```
var returnedEl = from XElement e in doc.Root.Elements where e.Element("release_date")> passedDate select e;
```

O what would be a another working and best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are very close to the solution

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("aa.xml");
DateTime passedDate  = new DateTime(2010,11,11);

var books = xDoc.Descendants("book")
              .Where(b=>DateTime.ParseExact(b.Element("release_date").Value,"yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)>passedDate)
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also work, it uses `XPathSelectElements` from `System.Xml.XPath` namespace:

```
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 11, 15);

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Data.xml");
        var result = doc.XPathSelectElements("books/book/release_date")
                        .Where(el => Convert.ToDateTime(el.Value) > dt);
```